# How to encrypt specific language in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I have encrypted some of the data. Here my encryption converter is AES-256-CBC.

```
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

class AESCipher(object):

   def __init__(self, key):  
       self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()


   def encrypt(self, raw):
       raw = self._pad(raw)
       iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
       cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
       return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def _pad(self, s):
       return s + (AES.block_size- len(s) % AES.block_size) * chr(AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)


 key = some key
 raw='한글 (한국말)이라고도하는 한국어는 남한과 한국의 공식 언어입니다'
 AESCipher_obj=AESCipher(key)
 val = AESCipher_obj.encrypt(raw)
 print(val)
```

When I execute my code it gives me that error.

```
 > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "aes2.py", line 27, in
    > <module>
    >     s= AESCipher_obj.encrypt(raw)   File "aes2.py", line 17, in encrypt
    >     return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py",
    > line 244, in encrypt
    >     return self._cipher.encrypt(plaintext) ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in lengt
```

My input data is in the Korean language but When I try with the English language it is working perfectly. So how to encrypt for a specific language?

Comment: try encrypting just up to the __`.`__

Comment: @MosheSlavin Can you tell me where ?

Comment: `raw = '한글 (한국말)이라고도하는 한국어는 남한과 한국의 공식 언어입니다.'`

Comment: @MosheSlavin I check that but same error raise

Comment: You must always encrypt byte arrays, never character strings. That may seem to work sometimes, but it is almost always wrong.

Comment: @rodrigo how to achieve that because I have not much more about the encryption

Comment: @HarshitTrivedi: You convert your string into bytes before feeding it to the `encrypt` function, using `encode()` as the answer by SumantoDinar comments. Also `encrypt()` should return the byte array instead of `b64encode` it. If the caller needs the base64 encode of that, then it can do the conversion.

Comment: @rodrigo Can you give your answer in answer box because I did not understand where I am changing my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you use a Python3 version, your string is an unicode string. You should encode it to an utf8 encoded byte string before padding it because the length will change. It works for ascii strings, because the length of the encoded byte string is the length of the unicode string.

So in your code, you must simply do:

```
 key = some key
 raw ='한글 (한국말)이라고도하는 한국어는 남한과 한국의 공식 언어입니다'
 byte_raw = raw.encode('utf8')
 AESCipher_obj=AESCipher(key)
 val = AESCipher_obj.encrypt(byte_raw)

 print(val)
```

After decrypting, you will get a byte string that should be decoded with `.decode('utf8')` to convert it to a Python3 (unicode) string.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Thank you for answering

Answer (score 2):

Your Error:

> ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length

[AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is a block cipher, it works on 16-byte (128-bit) blocks.

The data needs to be [padded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) until they're 16 bytes.

See this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/52114).

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

try to encode() your string into byte string maybe ? and then padding it.
you can see here https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py

that it's working with bytestring instead of unicode (you are using python3)
your step are correct, and I see nothing wrong with the padding mechanism